# CheckBox is checked send item to defferent activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-checkbox

In my application, When CheckBox is checked I want the item in the ListView to go to another ListView in another Activity. Please help me or give me some pointers on how to do this. I appreciate any help.

```
public class Check extends Activity{

CheckBox check;
TextView tvItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    tvItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){

            }else{

            }

        }
    });
}



}
```

What code should i put in the if and else.

Comment: It will be hard to help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to set an onClickedListener for the CheckBox, and start the activity passing enough information to start the new Activity with a ListView set right. You might need to toggle the state of the checkedBox, just in case I've included code for that, remove it if something looks wrong.

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    void onClick(View v) {
        checkedBox.toggle(); //Remove if check box is toggled correctly

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data",someData);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Other activity checks for an intent, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Magic happens here.
}
```

For more detail, read this [Android Document](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) article very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could bundle the information (such as the name of the item) and send it through to another activity via the Intent, either on check or through a button click.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        final String MSTag = "MSTag"; //declare this string as your tag
            String itemName = YOUR_LIST_ITEM_NAME

...
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YOUR_NEW_ACTIVITY.class);  
       myIntent.putExtra(MSTag, itemName); // add your tag and the item name to your intent.

       startActivity(m1Intent);
```

Then, in your new activity:

```
Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras(); // this gets your added extras from the previous activity
myTag = intent.getString("MSTag"); // matches on your tag, and gets the string value
String itemName = myTag;
...
```

Then add your item to your ListView in your new Activity